# Read outlook office 365 email using selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, outlook, office365

I need to read an email from client outlook office 365 during my execution of Web base testing using Selenium Java. Previously the code was working fine for host: mail.client.co.in (Outlook 2010/2016). Previously, Code use to read an email from my outlook without opening any web OWA. Now my email migrated to outlook.Office365.com and thus the below code fails.  I am using pop3 protocol to read an email.

End goal is to read an email and need to set the properties for reading an email using selenium java

Below is the Selenium script which I am using:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        String host = "outlook.office365.com";// change accordingly
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String mailStoreType = "pop3";
        String username = " client username";
        String password = "********";

        try {
            // create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable","true");

            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            emailSession.setDebug(true);

            // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

            store.connect(host, username, password);

            // create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            // System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
            for (int i = messages.length - 1; i == messages.length - 1; i--) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                // System.out.println(message.getSubject());
                String rvnmail = getTextFromMessage(message);
```

Console error:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.finalizecleanclose: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "outlook.office365.com", port 995, isSSL true
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: outlook.office365.com, 995; timeout -1;
```

nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out:connect com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:217)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)

Comment: Can you be sure this is not a network problem?
Can you connect to outlook.office365.com:995 using other tools? E.g. `telnet outlook.office365.com 995`

Comment: telnet isn't working. Error: Connecting To outlook.office365.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 995: Connect failed. I am working on my client Virtual machine and using OutlookOffice365, Previously scripts were working perfectly fine the only chnage in the code was host: mail.client.co.**. I tried to change host name to outlook.office365.com; however, it does not work.

Comment: Please, do configure you virtual machine to allow client access port I are trying to connect.

Comment: How can I configure? Currently As I have just started my career I would reqquest you to help me with detailed solution. I hope you dont mind it. Also I can to know that outlook.office365.com is cloud base and not feaseble to telnet from virtual machine. I would be more happy, If you can help me with further steps or  guidance.